How can I get the % address of a graphic object?
sorry if the example looks trivial. My real problem is a little nore compicated
If I execute
Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All];
Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^3 - y^3], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All];
GraphicsGrid[{{%1, %6}}, ImageSize -> {1400, 400}, Spacings -> 0, 
 Alignment -> Left]

I get the desired graphic output.
Where those %1 and %6 come from? How can I get them dynamically?
Thanks

For the first question... The %1347 is just a reference to a cell label. Notice in the left margin you'll see things like In[1347] and Out[1347]. The cell labels are created in sequence and updated if a cell is re-evaluated. So, you must have done at least 1347 cell evaluations so far during your session.

See the documentation for Out, which this use of % is used for. However, to do something like this idiomatically, it'd probably be better to save the plot to a variable: e.g. plot = Plot3D[...]; Show[plot, ImageSize -> Medium].

For the second question, I'm not sure what you mean by getting it dynamically. You'd have to get it from the cell that the thing is in that you want to reference, but if you already know what cell you want, then it seems unnecessary to get it dynamically. But if you just mean you want to have a reference to that cell that stays in sync with the cell label, then you can do that automatically in version 14. What version do you have? But this is kind of a "hack-y" way to do things. It would be better to use a symbol to hold the value that you want to reference (as I notice @eyorble just said).

Search for % in the Help > Wolfram Documentation center. For me, I get two hits, Mod and Out. The page for Out gives the answer.

%1 is the result of the 1st input. %6 is the result of the 6th input. %n is the result of the nth input. These are not very convenient to use: the number depends on when you started Mathematica and how many calculations you made since then.
Why don't you just assign these results to variables and refer to them that way instead?
fig1 = Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
fig2 = Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^3 - y^3], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
GraphicsGrid[{{fig1, fig2}}]


It works. Thanks

More practical usage is just %for the last result generated or %% for the result before last. %%…% (k times) for the k^(th) previous result.
Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All];
Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^3 - y^3], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All];
GraphicsGrid[{{%, %%}}, Spacings -> 0, Alignment -> Left]



